# Ebean fails to save a string with underscore

Tags: mysql, playframework, ebean

I am using the Play framework & Ebean (MySql).

When I try to save such string as below:

```
com.company.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzz.SomeClassName.someMethodName_XXXZ
```

Ebean throws the following exception:

```
[PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Duplicate entry 'com.company.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzz.SomeClassName.someMethod' for key 'Package_Name']]
```

When I replace the underscore in the string with minus (-) or anything else or I put the string in quotation marks, it works.

I cannot figure out why this happens and how to escape underscore in Ebean.

Any help/ideas?

Comment: From the error message it seems like the `Package_name` field has some kind of unique constraint set on it (explicit or as a primary key). So it quite possible that the value already exists in the database? have you tried submitting the string with the minus or the | more than once? if it throws the same error then that should indicate that my assumption is correct...

Comment: I checked it and  without underscores I can save it as many times as I want. There is a logic: when the string already exists, I will update the value. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's very odd. Can you show your SQL table definition and your class definition?

Comment: How long is the field? Does the whole string fit in or is it truncated?

Comment: @jsonmurphy, you were right. I rechecked the table constraints and this column had an index (and unique entry constraint subsequently). I removed the index and it worked. Thank you!